# How to Update Blazor Server App from .net core 6.03, to 6.04

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a .net core Blazor Server App which is currently using version 6.03 of .net core.

Version 6.04 came out a few days ago, and I need to upgrade the project and then publish it so it is using the new bits.

I have:

1. Install the latest SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) which includes 6.04.
2. I also used Nuget to ensure all libs are on 6.04.

However, when I open the project, and check the file versions, it is still using 6.03.

I have looked for any setting in the project file that would indicate which version of .net 6, it is using, but I don't see any such setting.  I only see this setting:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Is there some way to get VS to use 6.04 instead of 6.03?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of working with this, I found that the minor version is tied to the Version of Visual Studio that you are using.

So, I was using VS 2022 Version 17.2.0 Preview 4, and the .net 6.0.4 bits had not been released yet for this version. So those bits are not accessible from this version.

However, the 6.0.4 bits have been released for VS 2022 Version 17.1.5.  So by downloading and installing 17.1.5, the project then opened up using 6.0.4 without any other changes.

I am sure that soon the bits will be released for the 17.2 version soon.